# Is it possible to make a viewport that follows the player using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm wondering how to make a viewport that follows the player such as in sidescrolling games. I have a semi-working version, but it requires me to move everything except the player.

```
    ctx.translate(canvX,canvY);
    drawBlocks();
    ctx.restore()
```

This works for now, but I will have to draw enemies and other objects, and I don't want to constantly have to redo the process. I'm looking for a simple solution that basically involves a camera that follows the player. Is this possible?

Comment: You didn't really give enough code to help you, but either way you should try an Object Oriented approach or look into using a framework or library such as pixi.js  or phaser.io.

Comment: I'd assume the basic idea would be the same in all cases, but you can see the code I started with if it helps. https://www.codecademy.com/azhiguore/codebits/Jwh0VH

Comment: There's no way to just 'make' a camera. I did think of a hack though. You could make a really big canvas, put it inside a significantly smaller div, then move the canvas around inside the div as your player moves, but that has really big performance implications. My suggestion is to try using a game engine or some other library like the two I mentioned to see how they handle moving a bunch of sprites around a canvas easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like three.js for games.  Because you have to draw as many frames per second, and canvas just isn't great for that (if you don't believe me now, wait until you have to draw more things on the screen).

However, for your current code, one thing I notice is you're missing a `save`.

If that's not the problem, which I dont think it is, based on your question, you don't want to re-draw everything, only the background?  You could actually use multiple layers, so that each enemy is an HTML element, and you only redraw the enemy when their animation frame changes.  Then you just move their element ( a little cheaper than re-drawing in terms of performance ).

THREE.JS is what you should learn.. it will really help you out.

Comment: Again, using vanilla javascript is prefered. Is there a way to convert from three.js to javascript?

Comment: You are aware that the Three.js uses the canvas and offers no advantage in terms of speed (I would say actually slows the canvas down with unneeded overhead) over directly using the canvas and its various APIs

Comment: It uses a different context.  His code uses `translate`, which means he did `canvas.getContext('2d')` whereas threejs uses `webgl` instead of 2d.  webgl uses the video card ( many many pipes ) versus processor only (single pipe).  I don't know what you're trying to do that you'd wanna use vanilla only.  It's hard to give you guidance without more information.